# SQL Service Broker - Send Message Between databases with different Authorizations

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I'm trying to figure out how to set up the proper security to send a message from one database to another. The issue I'm having is that the sending database service is bound to a specific user via the authorization, because that service also sends messages to a remote service binding.

So here's my service:

```
CREATE SERVICE [WebRequestService]
    AUTHORIZATION WebDbSSBUser
    ON QUEUE [dbo].[WebRequestQueue]
    ([RequestContract],[CountRequestContract],[OrderRequestContract]);
GO
```

I want to send a message from that service to another service in a different local database as well. That service is:

```
CREATE SERVICE [AppRequestService]
    AUTHORIZATION DBO
    ON QUEUE [dbo].AppRequestQueue
    ([RequestContract]);
```

AppRequestService does not have to send messages to any remote bindings, so it's authorized by DBO. When I try to send:

```
declare @handle uniqueidentifier
begin dialog conversation @handle from service [WebRequestService] to service 'AppRequestService' on contract [RequestContract];
send on conversation @handle message type [AppRequest] (@item_data)
```

I get this in the transmission log:

> An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue.
>   Error: 916, State: 3. The server principal
>   "S-1-9-3-1771139253-1243890769-2689325230-2851569174" is not able to
>   access the database "appmembership" under the current security
>   context.

The sid is WebDbSSBUser.

Not sure how I should set up the permissions and I'd prefer to not have to set up a separate queue.

Comment: Also, worth noting, Trustworthy and Broker are both enabled.

Comment: You shouldn't need Trustworthy. I use login-less users in my environment so I don't have to worry about having the login on all replicas in an availability group. You can make these with `create user yourUser without login;` and it *should* work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use appmembership
go
create user WebDbSSBUser --for login WebDbSSBUser
go
grant send on service::AppRequestService to WebDbSSBUser
go
```

Comment: i didnt have a login for WebDbSSBUser, just a User without login as per most writeups i found. Changing to a Login, making the user in the target databse, and granting send (like above) fixed it.